# iOS 10 errors logged multiple times causing app to hang

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mpmusicplayercontroller, ios10

I have a music streamer app in the app store already. 
Now I am testing my app on iOS 10 via Xcode 8.0 beta.

My app keeps hanging at multiple places for few seconds. First is when launching the app itself, i see a black screen for few seconds. Then when launching any View Controller, same happens. When dismissing a view controller, same happens.

Everytime the following error is logged multiple times. When this error stops logging, then the action finishes. I am not finding any hits of this error on the web:

```
2016-06-15 21:05:38.407727 APPNAME[1623:409190] [SDKPlayback] MPMusicPlayer: Unable to launch iPod music player server: security policy error
2016-06-15 21:05:38.920961 APPNAME[1623:409190] [SDKPlayback] MPMusicPlayer: Unable to launch iPod music player server: security policy error
2016-06-15 21:05:39.437162 APPNAME[1623:409190] [SDKPlayback] MPMusicPlayer: Unable to launch iPod music player server: security policy error
2016-06-15 21:05:39.950330 APPNAME[1623:409190] [SDKPlayback] MPMusicPlayer: Unable to launch iPod music player server: security policy error
```

My app is a music streamer. I am not sure if i should wait for the next beta release to test or report this as a bug or something?

Comment: perhaps your url to that stream is not secure, in that case you should allow non secure url which is done via plist file, or simply use https

Comment: I had added that security policy exception to plist already when iOS 9 came out. Also this happens even before the app streams anything - just upon the app launch with a black screen. Everything does work and streams fine eventually after the lags.

Comment: Strange, it sound like offending code is running inside of appdelegate.

Answer (score 2):

Invoking operations on a MPMusicPlayerController instance without first checking that it is prepared to play will cause the described behavior (security warnings and the application will hang). The following code without checking *mediaPlayer.isPreparedToPlay* when run on a simulator will replicate the behavior:

```
MPMusicPlayerController *mediaPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];
if (mediaPlayer.isPreparedToPlay) {
  mediaPlayer.repeatMode = MPMusicRepeatModeAll;
  mediaPlayer.shuffleMode = MPMusicShuffleModeSongs;
}
```

And in swift :

```
let mediaPlayer = MPMusicPlayerController.applicationMusicPlayer()
if mediaPlayer.isPreparedToPlay {
  mediaPlayer.repeatMode = MPMusicRepeatMode.All
  mediaPlayer.shuffleMode = MPMusicShuffleMode.Songs
}
```

Comment: Yeah this is swift, the question is tagged with Objective C

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The code is easily translatable, I added an objective C snippet

Comment: sorry, the issue has been fixed since then. It was related to iOS 10 beta issues which got resolved later on beta updates

Comment: I am still seeing this issue in the iOS 10.2 simulator, although the log not includes more info ```MPMusicPlayer: Unable to launch iPod music player server: Error Domain=FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain Code=3 "Entitlement "com.apple.frontboard.launchapplications" is required to open applications in this manner." UserInfo={BSErrorCodeDescription=Security, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Entitlement "com.apple.frontboard.launchapplications" is required to open applications in this manner.}```